# How to get text (label) of all checkboxes

Tags: selenium, checkbox, webdriver

I've been trying to get the label value inside all the checkboxes in a page, so far i have been using this code to automate the HTML below.

**JAVA**:

```java
List<WebElement> allCBox = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));
for(WebElement checkbox : allCBox ) {
    System.out.println("--- "+checkbox.gettext()); 
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<html>
  <p> Regions:
    south <input type="checkbox" name="south" value="south">&nbsp;
    british <input type="checkbox" name="british" value="british">&nbsp;
    north <input type="checkbox" name="north" value="north">&nbsp;
    southeast <input type="checkbox" name="southeast" value="southeast">&nbsp;
    west <input type="checkbox" name="west" value="west">&nbsp;
    Spanish <input type="checkbox" name="spanish" value="spanish">&nbsp;
    europian <input type="checkbox" name="europian" value="europian">&nbsp;
    northeast <input type="checkbox" name="northeast" value="northeast">
  </p>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to mark up your embedded html; it isn't being displayed properly.

Answer (score 3):

In your case `<input>` doesn't have text attribute, but labels are equal to "name" and "value" attribute. So you can just get "name" or "value" attribute.

```java
List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']"));

for(WebElement checkbox : CHECKBOXlist) {
    System.out.println(checkbox.getAttribute("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below logic.

```
List<WebElement> checkboxList=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[type='checkbox']"))
for(WebElement checkbox : CHECKBOXlist)
{
    if(checkbox.getAttribute("name").length()>=6)
    {
           checkbox.click();
    }
}
```

FYI : I've seen your html page from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/webdriver/adyz0WFzZj0)